# Cannot assign value of type 'JSONObject.Type' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>.Type') to type 'JSONObject' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>')

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, I'm trying to write a simple class following a course on lynda.com
This code works fine in the video but throws up an error on my system.

```
protocol JSONDecodable{
    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) throws
}
typealias JSONObject = [String: Any]

class JSONDecoder{
    let jsonObject: JSONObject

    init(_ jsonObject: JSONObject)
    {
        self.jsonObject = JSONObject
    }
}
```

This gives the following compilation error,

```
Cannot assign value of type 'JSONObject.Type' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>.Type') to type 'JSONObject' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>')
```

What am I missing here

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
self.jsonObject = JSONObject
```

with

```
self.jsonObject = jsonObject
```

and you may make `var jsonObject: JSONObject`